# How can I change the tempdir used by multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

multiprocessing apparently uses a tempdir to do its thing:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import util
>>> util.get_temp_dir()
'/tmp/pymp-f4hdy9d_'
```

Unfortunately I can find no information about the `util` module in the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), and by doing tab-tab I can't see any function like `set_temp_dir()` anyways.

So how can I change the `tempdir` ?

Comment: figured it out, need to set `TMPDIR` env var